# Getting json response from servlet to Android

Tags: android, json, servlets

I have a servlet that has the following purpose:

Receive data via the URL (that is, using get). Then returns a message, based on this input, back to the caller. I am new to this stuff, but have come to learn that using json (actually, Gson) is suitable for this.

My question now is, how do I retrieve this json message? What URL do I target? The relevant lines in the servlet are:

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(thelist);
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().println(json);
```

This is how I try to retrieve the json:

```
try{
            DefaultHttpClient defaultClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet("http://AnIPno:8181/sample/response?first=5&second=92866");
            HttpResponse httpResponse = defaultClient.execute(httpGetRequest);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
            String json = reader.readLine();
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);

} catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

But apparently this does not work, as I have found jsonObject has a size of 0 (it should be an array with three elements).

Previously, I had a write() instead of println() in the servlet. I'm not sure if that matters in this case. But I'm assuming I've misunderstood something about how the json object is retrieved. Is it not enough to point it towards the URL of the servlet?

Comment: just a note, use jackson-json with its object-mapper, it's faster and more dynamic than gson

Answer (score 0):

I have this function to readJsonData from a a request to a JSON String. You can use this function to  retrieve the JSON, then use GSON to parse it to the object that you like. It works for my application. Hope it works for you too.

```
    protected String readJson(HttpResponse resp)
        throws IOException {

        BufferedReader reader = null;  

        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    resp.getEntity().getContent()));
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            int read;
            char[] chars = new char[1024];
            while ((read = reader.read(chars)) != -1)
                buffer.append(chars, 0, read);
        } finally {
            if (reader != null)
                reader.close();
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }
```

So based on your code. I guess this should work:

```
String jsonData = readJson(httpResponse);
YourObject obj = new Gson().fromJson(jsonData, YourObject.class);
```

Before trying this, make sure your servlet prints out the JSON data that you want. I suggest using these Chrome Extensions: Postman - REST Client and JSON Formatter, to test your data from servlet. It's pretty helpful.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what it was. But pasting that readJson function didn't quite work. For starters, I had to specify the type of reader and buffer (which seems normal to me), and then in the finally block, it wouldn't recognize the variables reader or buffer.

So I still haven't solved this. But those Chrome extensions look great.

It shows me my servlet indeed creates this json String: ["entry1","entry2","entry3"]

Comment: `reader` variable didn't get recognized in the finally block is probably because you declare `reader` inside the `try` block. Bring it outside (see my updated code), it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Reading an `InputStream` whether from a File on the file system or from an HTTP request is, in most cases, the same.

What you have is correct only if your servlet wrote a single line. If the `Gson` object `toString()` method returns multiple lines, you're going to have to read multiple lines from the `InputStream`. I like to use the `Scanner` class for reading from an `InputStream`.

```
try {
    DefaultHttpClient defaultClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet("http://localhost:8080/cc/jsonyeah");
    HttpResponse httpResponse = defaultClient.execute(httpGetRequest);

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8");       

    while(scanner.hasNextLine()) { // scanner looks ahead for an end-of-line
        json += scanner.nextLine() + "\n"; // read the full line, you can append a \n
    }               
    // do your serialization
} catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

So we've done the same thing we would've done if we were reading from a file. Now the `json` object contains the json you received from the servlet, as a `String`.

For the serialization, you have a few options.

A `Gson` object has an overloaded method `fromJson()` that can take a `String` or a `Reader`, among other things.

From where we are with the code above, you can do

```
MyClass instance = new Gson().fromJson(json, MyClass.class);
```

where `MyClass` is the type you are trying to create. You will have to use a `TypeToken` for generic classes (such as a list). `TypeToken` is an abstract class, so generate an anonymous class and call `getType()`

```
Type type = new com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType();
List<MyClass> list = new Gson().fromJson(json, type);
```

Another option is to use the overloaded method that takes a Reader directly instead of reading line by line from the InputStream:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
MyClass instance = new Gson().fromJson(reader , MyClass.class);
```

You'll get to skip a step.

Don't forget to close your streams.

Comment: Thanks for all of this. The Json output looks like this: ["entry1","entry2","entry3"] So from the looks of it, it's an array. But it's really a String representation of an array, right? I am still having troubles understanding how I am to retrieve the contents of this array (or list) to separate Strings within my app.

Comment: I am trying this now for serialization:

instance = new Gson().fromJson(json, String.class);

I'm not sure what else is needed? This compiles, but it's not enough? I try to use the String instance in debugging, but when I do  Log.i("mytrololololol", instance); nothing appears in the Logcat.

Comment: Doing List<String> list = new Gson().fromJson(json, new TypeToken<List<Strierrors: ng>>()); results in two errors. First: The method fromJson(String, Class<T>) in the type Gson is not applicable for the arguments (String, TypeToken<List<String>>) then: The constructor TypeToken<List<String>>() is not visible.

Comment: Sorry, look at my edit. use `new com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType();` TypeToken is an abstract class.

Comment: I can't believe how hard it seems to be for me to learn this. I looked at your latest example. Defined a List<String> called list earlier, then used Type type = new com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken<List<String>>(){}.getType();
list = new Gson().fromJson(json, type);

It asks me what 'Type' to import. I try them all, but only java.lang.protect.Type seems to work. So when I try to use this list (for example via assigning list.size() to some int), the program crashes :(

Comment: Ooops, typo on my part. I did get it right within the actual project, though. And I'm having a super hard time making sense of the logcat output files. I have no idea why this doesn't work. When I try this json in regular Java, I manage to print it just fine.

Comment: @ChristoferOlsson Take a step back. Make a plain java project and try to run it. IF it works, try the exact same code with Android. I hope you are aware of network capabilities of Android phones and the permissions required.

Comment: I have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> in my AndroidManifest.xml, I assume that is sufficient. I will try to use the exact Java code right away. For some reason, I didn't think I could.

Comment: When I use the exact same code on Android, the app crashes right away. Well, almost the same, I had to surround things in a try/catch block in Android that I didn't have to in Java.

Comment: But of course, when I put the same try/catch in regular Java, it still works. I want to kill myself.

Comment: @ChristoferOlsson Developing for Android is developing in Java. It's the same thing. Your methods must have different definitions with `throws` or something.

Comment: I am being told this is because of a NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: @ChristoferOlsson That's it. You cannot do network connections in the main thread. Search for it on this site, there are plenty of solutions. You have to do it in a separate thread, maybe an `AsyncTask`.